# Create a co-occurrence matrix from a .csv

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to create a co-occurrence matrix to see what keywords are frequently associated together in my database.

The data looks like this, it's a .csv file.

```
id,    keywords
1,     apple;pear
2,     apple;cherry
3,     pear;cherry
4,     apple;cherry
```

And I would like to obtain something like this

```
          apple  pear  cherry
apple       0      1      2
pear        1      0      1
cherry      2      1      0
```

The goal would then be to use d3.js to visualize the matrix.

I've posted this in the `R` tag because I've used it a bit before for some classes, so I'm not a complete newbie. I saw while looking for solutions that it's also possible to use python to do this, but I never touched it in my life.

Comment: I found [this way](https://www.r-bloggers.com/turning-keywords-into-a-co-occurrence-network/) of doing it that seems to work perfectly fine for what I want to do !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tidyr` (and `magrittr`) package(s) and the `table` function.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, keywords = c("apple;pear", "apple;cherry", "pear;cherry", "apple;cherry"))

df2 <- df %>% separate(keywords, sep = ";", into = c("F1", "F2"))
```

This is to have the correct levels in your row/column names.

```
df2$F1 %<>% factor() 
df2$F2 %<>% factor()

df2$F1 <- factor(df2$F1, levels = unique(c(levels(df2$F1), levels(df2$F2))))
df2$F2 <- factor(df2$F2, levels = unique(c(levels(df2$F1), levels(df2$F2))))
```

You can now use table (it's not symmetric so use `+`)

```
> table(df2$F1, df2$F2) + table(df2$F2, df2$F1)

         apple pear cherry
  apple      0    1      2
  pear       1    0      1
  cherry     2    1      0
```

Comment: `df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, keywords = c("apple;pear", "apple;cherry", "pear;cherry", "apple;cherry"))`

Do I have to enter the keywords manually? In my data frame I have a bit more than 200, so it's gonna be a bit complicated.

Comment: Oh no, it's just to use your example. Use `read.csv` for that.

Comment: Hey so it's working fine, but the problem is that I didn't ask my question right. I made it seem like their is only 2 keywords per line, but that number can change. Sometimes you have one keyword, sometimes four, etc. So the `into = c("F1", "F2"))` isn't the right solution here. @MrSnake

Comment: And there also seems to be a problem with the lines where you use factor, it puts `NA` everywhere in the matrix. Even with the sample code you provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you're right, with 3 words or more, it can't work. However, I started a new R session and the code works and gives the output I wrote.